# How to set add a new Header in Request in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi I am using Spring Boot 2.1.1 and I have written REST end points. If a request comes, it needs to be validated, based upon validation, I need add to add a new Request header as "NEW_SES_VAL_ID" and value as "12345". I have written interceptor also but I am unable to add to Request Header. Please help about how to add a new Request header in every incoming request in Interceptor in Spring Boot.

Comment: Please provide the code of your interceptor. If you debug your program is the interceptor code getting run?

Comment: what does your interceptor look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interceptor extending `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`

Something like this:

```
public class MyCustomInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        // some code ...

        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
        headers.add("MyHeader", "headerValue");

       // more code ...

       return execution.execute(request, body);
    }

   //Rest of the class
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I can not add the following code.

Comment: registry.addInterceptor(myCustomInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/");

Comment: My class looks like this. public class EMWebConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer { }